# Transform IObservable of strings into IObservable of XDocuments

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<string>` that contains (fragments of) XML documents. I'd like to transform one into the other. So for example, suppose I have the following fragments that are pushed from my `IObservable<string>` (each line contains a fragment):

```
<?xml version=
"1.0" ?>
<testXml></test
Xml><?xml version="1.0"
?><otherXml /><?xm
```

How can I morph this into an `IObservable<XDocument>` to get the following documents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><testXml />
<?xml version="1.0"?><otherXml />
```

I've been thinking about handing the `IObservable<string>` to some blocking `TextReader` implementation but I think there should be a more clever solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
IObservable<string> splitXmlTokensIntoSeparateLines(string s)
{
    // Here, you need to split tokens into separate lines (where 'token'
    // is the beginning of an Xml element). This makes it easier down
    // the line for the TakeWhile operator.

    return new[] { firstPart, secondPart, etc }.ToObservable();
}

bool doesTokenTerminateDocument(string s)
{
    // Here, you should return whether the XML represents the end of one 
    // document
}

var xmlDocuments = stringObservable
    .SelectMany(x => splitXmlTokensIntoSeparateLines(x))
    .TakeWhile(x => doesTokenTerminateDocument(x))
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (acc, x), acc.Append(x))
    .Select(x => {
        var ret = new XDocument();
        ret.Parse(x.ToString());
        return ret;
    })
    .Repeat()
    .TakeUntil(stringObservable.Aggregate(0, (acc, _) => acc));
```

The TakeUntil is a hack to make it terminate correctly - basically, Repeat would keep resubscribing forever, unless we stop it by telling it to finish when stringObservable completes.

Comment: Hm, this should work. But I may have made my example XML too simple :) In reality, the XML docs are larger and have child nodes. This makes it pretty hard to keep track of when a document ends (because it doesn't always start with the same element).

Comment: Couldn't you just look for "<?xml"?  The only thing you really need to split is the ending of one XML document and the beginning of another

Comment: Agreed. But what happens when this declaration is divided over two lines? I'm beginning to think I need to implement some sort of state machine using `Observable.Scan`.

Comment: It's fine if the Xml declaration is split over two lines, it will all be appended together later

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't use the `Select` operator?

```
var xmlObs = stringObs.Select(s => {
  var x = new XDocument();
  x.Parse(s);
  return x;
});
```

Comment: Because I get incomplete XML fragments from my observable, not complete XML documents.

Comment: @Ronald: You *cannot* convert something that isn't an XML Document into a `XDocument`. Either you have valid XML or you have nothing.

Comment: I understand that. But when I append all XML fragments in my question, I get a sequence of valid XML documents. However, this is not an option because I can receive an endless sequence of fragments of XML documents. My `IObservable<string>` pushes _parts of_ valid XML documents.